# Rails - disable js&css //=require for tests

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, rspec

When running tests in a Rails (5) app, let's say controller rspecs for example,  you need to have all external frontend dependencies available - anything that's included from `application.js` or `application.css` is needed to run these tests, otherwise you get a `Sprockets::FileNotFound` exception when the code gets to rendering the response.

That's not actually needed because we're not evaluating the resulting HTML or any such thing, and definitely not running the JS, but it makes those tests depend on npm/bower not failing, takes time downloading, etc. etc.

So, I'm hoping to find a way to not need js & css dependencies when running specs - essentially making `application.js` and `application.css` empty for the purpose of that spec run. (Except that doesn't work because other templates may `require` things too.)

Has anyone done such a thing? How? :)

Comment: `describe 'some stuff which doesn't require js', js: false do` could work for you?

Comment: @fabersky apparently not. It looks like accessing `image_path` for example, triggers Sprockets to read application.js for a list of dependencies, and fail with es6-shim missing (because that's the first one)

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this by just including the dependencies in the test environment, with Sprockets enabled it's just part of the Rails boot process, I don't believe there's an easy way around it.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually something I haven't considered. The list of dependencies is *relatively* static, so it might be easy to just create those as empty files and be done with it :).

(That said, I'm reluctant to mark this as accepted answer, sorry, still hoping for something a bit cleaner :))

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this by doing.. in the test environment.

`class << ActionController::Base.helpers
  def image_path(path, options = {})
    path
  end
end`

Turns out, not using image path (and possibly other related helpers, YMMV) doesn't trigger the lookups.